# How to make a div with a background image clickable

Tags: html, css, href

Im trying to make this div clickable:

```
 <a href="{{ url_for('germany') }}">
            <div class="item item--germany">
                <div class="item__details">
                    Germany 
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
```

The div is a background image and when I try to link it like above, the image become 1/8 of its size and the text has a funky line in it. Here is the CSS:

```
.item {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #0c9a9a;
  color: #fff;
  grid-column-start: auto;
  grid-row-start: auto;
  color: #fff;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470124182917-cc6e71b22ecc?dpr=2&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=1000&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px 0px rgba(56, 41, 41, 0.4);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  counter-increment: item-counter;
}

.item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.3;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.item:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
          transform: scale(1.05);

.item--germany {
    background-image: url("../images/germany.jpg");
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none; /* no underline */
  }
```

I read I could do something like `<a href><img="image.jpg></a>` but that would remove my div and I don't think that the hover effect would still work.

Answer (score 0):

What are you testing the code on? I sometimes use the websites repl.it or codepen.io to test my code if it isn't going to plan on my laptop